# pgadmin4 401 Unauthorized in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, pgadmin

I get the message: "The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."

I installed pgadmin 4 with the commands: sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
And configured everything, but it does not give me access.

I found that I can access the log file: ~/.pgAdmin4.startup.log and copy the URL with the key, but having to do this each time after the 401 Error is not feasible.

What did I do wrong during the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping `%URL%` in the Browser Command setting with quotation marks seems to fix the problem for me. To do that, right-click the pgAdmin icon in *Status & Notifications* area, select *Configure*, and in the *Browser Command* field enter

```
/usr/bin/firefox "%URL%"
```

Note the `"`s.

---

*My original answer was:*

I'm having the same issue on an older version of Kubuntu (16.04), and while I have no real solution, here's an easier workaround:

Once you launch pgAdmin and it opens a browser that shows you that `HTTP 401 error` message, you'll find a pgAdmin icon in *Status & Notifications* area of the system tray. Right-click it and select *Copy server URL*. You can then open this URL in your browser, and it should log you in properly.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I am doing right now, but I would like to find a way to not have to do it every single time.

Comment: @JorgePaladines , I have found a better solution and edited my answer accordingly, hopefully it will help you as well.

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you very much

Comment: I have tested this from the command line and it works perfectly. Unfortunately, I can't seem to change it in the config (read-only dialog). Do you happen to know where the config file is that stores that?